# How can I use SnapKit achieve this?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I want is like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    let label1 = UILabel()
    let label2 = UILabel()
    label1.textColor = .white
    label1.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(label1)
    label1.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
        m.left.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
        m.top.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
    }
    view.addSubview(label2)
    label2.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
        m.left.equalTo(label1.snp.right)
        m.top.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
        m.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-100)
    }
    label1.text = "123456"
    label2.text = "789"
```

it works like this:
[image]

Why is it not aligned to the left?
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove** your *right* constraint for `label2`.

```
label2.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
    m.left.equalTo(label1.snp.right)
    m.top.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
    // m.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-100)
}
```

Your `label2` has been attached to the super view's left at a distance of 100. So because `label1` has no width set, it will *resize* itself to respect the right constraint of `label2`, thereby satisfying all the constraints that you have set.

If you cannot remove the left constraint, then you need to get the width of the label without any constraints for a text. You can get it like this. For example,

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Blah"
let width = label.intrinsicContentSize.width
```

Now you set this width using snapKit to the width of label1. and set the left constraint less than or equal to 100.

**Alternatively** and the **better** approach, You could also try having a single label with attributed text. Since you know the string of the first label and the second label, you can easily format it with `NSAttributedString` avoiding the headache of constraints for multiple labels.

```
let string1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Your first string", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.red])
let string2 = NSAttributedString(string: "Your second string", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.white])
var finalString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
finalString.append(string1)
finalString.append(string2)
```

Now set the anchors as 10 right, top, -10 left.

Comment: I can't because I need this constraint, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Lixiang why? Did it work when you removed it? You might want to give attributed strings a try then.

Comment: Do you have a way to make label1's width just equal to it's text's width?

Comment: @Lixiang _"I can't because I need this constraint"_ _"WHY?"_

Comment: It should not overstep the boundary

Comment: @Lixiang then it is a lot more complicated as you have to tell which label should truncate in case the size of both of the labels exceed the available size. You can check this to get the width of the label for a particular text. I strongly recommend you use a single string with attributed text though.

Comment: I can calculate label1's text width and then constrain it with width, but I wonder if there's any simpler way to do that.

Comment: @Lixiang check the edit. I haven't tested it. Let me know if the attributed string approach works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very detailed and accurate.